# Custom coalesce JPA query using SpEL

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-el, coalesce

I'm using Hibernate with Spring Data and I'm trying to create a custom coalesce query using SpEL in the following fashion:

```
@Modifying
@Query("UPDATE Order o SET o.serial = COALESCE(?#{#another.serial}, o.serial), " +
        "o.owner = COALESCE(?#{#another.owner}, o.owner)")
Order nullSafeUpdate(@Param("another") Order another);
```

the result of this is the following

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Using named parameters for method public abstract test.test.test.test.Order test.test.test.test.OrderRepository.nullSafeUpdate(test.test.test.test.Order) but parameter 'another' not found in annotated query 'UPDATE Order o SET o.serial = COALESCE(?#{#another.serial}, o.serial), o.owner = COALESCE(?#{#another.owner}, o.owner)'!
```

I've already tried replacing **?** with **:** based on these [guidelines](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions) and removing the **#**.

The **Order** entity has both public getters and setters for all variables.

Using Spring Data **1.6.6**

**UPDATE**

Seems like the **JpaQueryMethod** validator **assertParameterNamesInAnnotatedQuery** does not even check for parameters included in a SpEL form

```
if (!annotatedQuery.contains(String.format(":%s", parameter.getName()))) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format(
                    "Using named parameters for method %s but parameter '%s' not found in annotated query '%s'!", method,
                    parameter.getName(), annotatedQuery));
        }
```